# How to select a DOM element in JavaScript?

Tags: dom, select, element

I want the user to be able to select the contents of a  element by clicking it once. The code would look like this:

```
<div onclick="this.xyz()">...</div>
```

The question is: what method goes where I wrote xyz? I've searched for things like "DOM select object," but the answer is a needle hidden in a haystack of irrelevant hits (or not).

Comment: What do you mean "select the contents"? Do you want the contents passed to a function? Or do you want to copy them to the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'd want:

```
<div onclick="var contents = this.innerText;">foo bar</div>
```

which would set `contents` equal to `foo bar`. Of course, this isn't exactly cross-platform compatible. Firefox expects `.textContent` instead of `.innerText`. If you're not opposed to using jquery, then

```
<div onclick="var contents = $(this).text()">foo bar</div>
```

would do just as well and be cross-platform.